# How to convert TypeScript object type to union type like Object.values() in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a type like this:

```
type MyType = {
  type1: {
    type1property: string;
  };
  type2: {
    type2property: number;
  };
};
```

How can I convert above `MyType` to `Result` like this:

```
type Result =
  | {
      type1property: string;
    }
  | {
      type2property: number;
    };
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just lookup by available keys:

```
type Result = MyType[keyof MyType];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQUqkgRgC50tsck8wAnAe0ktCIGdhKBLAOwHMBuEgX17ZcEAExFMpMpBFVaEeiCLsArgFsARvMFQBGXRmFQAShEbKANsCio4iSAG0A1hBDUAZrARIAuryA)

---

Or reusable:

```
type Values<T> = T[keyof T];

type Result = Values<MyType>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQUqkgRgC50tsck8wAnAe0ktCIGdhKBLAOwHMBuEgX17ZcEAExFMpMpBFVaEeiCLsArgFsARvMFQBGXRmFQAagEMANsoiMAPPAB8UVPADaAawghqAMyjwAurwGSFAASlbKZsCOxuaWNnCIkHa8QA)